# No puedo acceder a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un host en "donweb.com" y tengo la información de la base de datos que ellos me aportaron, pero no puedo acceder a ella porque me manda estos errores:

Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'c1541183_intbase'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in (mi documento).

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_files\Mercadolibre\registro.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main}

```
php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
header('Location: index.php');}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

$errores = '';

if (empty($usuario) or empty($password) or empty($password2)) {
    $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
} else {
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=c1541183_intbase', 'c1541183_intbase', 'XXXXXXXX');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
    $statement->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
    $resultado = $statement->fetch();

    if ($resultado != false) {
        $errores .= '<li>El nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
    }

    $password = hash('sha512', $password);
    $password2 = hash('sha512', $password2);

    if ($password != $password2) {
        $errores .= '<li>Las contraseñas no son iguales</li>';
    }
}

if ($errores == '') {
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (id, usuario, pass) VALUES (null, :usuario, :pass)');
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':usuario' => $usuario,
        ':pass' => $password
    ));

    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

}

Me dijeron que el problema era que antes tenía "mysql:host=localhost" y que eso a veces no dirigía al própio localhost, así que la otra opcion era poner mi ip.

Comment: El error habla de una variable indefinida: `Undefined variable: conexion` si no pones el contexto completo no podremos revisar.

Comment: Habla de la variable indefinida "conexion" que es la línea 23: 
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');

Comment: Pon el código completo. La variable se define en el `try`, pero no se sabe si estás en una clase por ejemplo. Parece que el código no pasa por el `try`, no se puede determinar cuál es el error sin ver el contexto completo.

Comment: Disculpe, ahí edite el post mostrando todo el código.

Comment: prueba mysql:host=www.donweb.com en la variable $conexion

Comment: JGuerreroS, SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexi�n ya que la parte conectada no respondi� adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexi�n establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.

Comment: Asegurate de que el usuario y la contraseña son correctos
PDOSQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Este error te deniega el acceso y por lo cual NO te está creando la variable conexion.

Comment: Tienes que organizar bien tu código. El problema no es sólo que la conexión no se esté creando, sino que en una parte del código usas `$conexion` sin que ésta se haya creado. Lo lógico sería que: o bien declares `$conexion` como `NULL` por defecto y evalúes su estado antes de usarla o que traslades toda la lógica referente a la conexión al bloque `try`. Eso aparte de que puedas conectar o no. que es ya otro tema.